# 400 Bad Request while posting to InfluxDB with NativeEthernet

Tags: https, arduino, influxdb, ethernet, teensy

For a project we are trying to monitor a status protocol sent on local network over TCP and post these status messages over HTTPS to a InfluxDB instance on AWS at https://www.influxdata.com/products/influxdb-cloud/.

We are using a teensy 4.1 with a ethernet kit in combination with the Native Ethernet library by vjmuzik https://github.com/vjmuzik/NativeEthernet.

Posting a string to a test instance over LAN to a IP works fine, but whenever we try to post to the AWS subdomain we are greeted with this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 27 Sep 2021 18:13:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 122
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Since we verified the headers and body of the post are correct when we post locally, and posting to AWS works when using Postman, we are at a loss at the moment. Unfortunately I have no information about the configuration of the server we try to POST to.

We have tried:

- Using different ethernet libraries, at the moment we are using
  NativeEthernet from vjmuzik https://github.com/vjmuzik/NativeEthernet
- Different sets of headers
- Adding google dns in ethernet.begin()
- Post over http followed by a post over https after following the
  redirect response generated by the plain html request
- Adding certificates
- Verifying the InfluxDB line protocol with postman

As a test we set-up the WebClientRepeatingTLS example using our own POST headers and body.

```
#include <NativeEthernet.h>

uint8_t mac[6];
void teensyMAC(uint8_t *mac) {
  for (uint8_t by = 0; by < 2; by++) mac[by] = (HW_OCOTP_MAC1 >> ((1 - by) * 8)) & 0xFF;
  for (uint8_t by = 0; by < 4; by++) mac[by + 2] = (HW_OCOTP_MAC0 >> ((3 - by) * 8)) & 0xFF;
  Serial.printf("MAC: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
}

// initialize the library instance:
EthernetClient client;
const int port = 443;

char server[] = "influxdata.com";  

//IPAddress server(192, 168, 1, 246);

String outputMSG = "measurementName,tagKey=tagValue fieldKey=1i";
unsigned long lastConnectionTime = 0;           // last time you connected to the server, in milliseconds
const unsigned long postingInterval = 5 * 1000; // delay between updates, in milliseconds

void setup() {
  teensyMAC(mac);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; 
  }

  Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
      while (true) {
        delay(1);
      }
    }
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
  } else {
    Serial.print("  DHCP assigned IP ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }
  if (millis() - lastConnectionTime > postingInterval) {
    httpRequest();
  }

}

void httpRequest() {
  client.stop();
  Serial.print("Content-Length: ");
  Serial.println(outputMSG.length());
  Serial.println("");

  if (client.connect(server, port, true)) { 
    Serial.println("connecting to ");
    Serial.print(server);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(port);

        client.println("POST /api/v2/write?org=ORG_HERE&bucket=BUCKET_HERE&precision=s HTTP/1.1");
        client.println("Host: https://eu-central-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com");
        client.println("Authorization: Token <<TOKEN HERE>>");
        client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
        client.print("Content-Length: ");
        client.println(outputMSG.length());
        client.println("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
        client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
        client.println();
        client.println(outputMSG);
        client.println();
        
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}
```

Could anyone help us understand why the post to aws is not going through?

Cheers,
Boy

Comment: remove https:// from Host header

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have tried this in the past but get the following response:

    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Server: awselb/2.0
    Date: Sat, 02 Oct 2021 09:54:02 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 0
    Connection: close
    Location: https://www.influxdata.com/api/v2/write

Upon which I tried to make a new request by following the 301, unfortunately that still resulted in the original 400 bad request response.

Comment: the Host header should only contain the host name. the 301 is a step forward, the 400 is a step back

Comment: I see. Would you happen to know how to proceed from that point on?

Comment: why is your Host field different then the host name used for connect?

Comment: Excellent question, whenever I use eu-central-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com instead of influxdata.com I cannot connect to the server and the serial monitor would just print "connection failed".

Comment: did you try to put only influxdata.com  into the Host header?

Comment: No I have not, good one. I just checked it and when I use both influxdata.com as the server to connect to as well as using it as the host in the request it results in the same 301 response as before. If I use eu-central-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com as the server to connect to and influxdata.com as the host it won't connect to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [EthernetWebServerSSL](https://github.com/khoih-prog/EthernetWebServer_SSL) library in combination with the[QNEthernet](https://github.com/ssilverman/QNEthernet) library made it possible for the teensy to connect to the AWS subdomain and therefor allowed it to post to the Influxdb database.